# Can AutoFS keep a share permanently mounted on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, automounting, autofs, unmounting

I have a share mounted on an Oracle Solaris application server that read/writes data onto the share periodically. I have automounted it with a timeout of over several minutes but is there a way to ensure it never unmounts the share? Looking at the man pages on the Solaris box and the [reference docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1454/rfsrefer-13.html#rfsrefer-64), it seems there is no such option unless I missed it somewhere.

On Linux, it seems [automount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/automount) offers such a facility - we need to set the timeout as 0, to disable unmounting of the share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display or configure SMF autofs properties by using the sharectl command. For example

```
  # sharectl get autofs
    timeout=600
    automount_verbose=false
    automountd_verbose=false
    nobrowse=false
    trace=0
    environment=
  # sharectl set -p timeout=200 autofs
```

You can check out this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1450/chapter6-2.html) for details

if you like to setup a permanent mount then why don't you use direct maps. Here is a detail [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1454/rfsrefer-66.html#rfsrefer-72) for direct autofs maps.